# Web Log analysis in Java

Tags: java, file-io, log-analysis

How to read a web server log file in Java. This file is getting updated all the time.  If I open a new FileInputStream, will it read the log real time?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on RandomAccessFile:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=226