# How to read a log file and parse the entries in Java?

Tags: java, file

I have silly question, but I'm unprofessional. I am trying to make a logs reader in Java, which will read the logs from directory. It must recognizes errors,informations and warnings. Which solution will be the best(the fastest) in this case: FileInputStream with BufferedReader or FileReader with BufferedReader? Or maybe something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Log analysis in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131176/web-log-analysis-in-java)

Comment: Not really. The OP is asking for the fastest method to read from a file, not a way to read a file in real-time.

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));
String line1 = in.readLine();
```

is about as fast as you can get. `BufferedReader` buffers your input so it's faster than simply using `FileReader`. And in case you were wondering, `Scanner` is significantly slower than `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1):

For choosing between a FileInputStream or a FileReader, it depends on what you want to work with - bytes (FileInputStream) or text / characters 'a', 'b', ... (FileReader). If you have the log files as plain text, it would make sense to use a FileReader.

Note that a FileReader uses an encoding, read the JavaDoc.